# Div Margin-top Not Changing?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, menu

I have a menu-like div that I'd like to slide down. I'd also like the margin-top of the div underneath the menu div (the content div) to go down, so that the content div gets closer to the edge of the margin div as the margin div expands. This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var charter = document.getElementById("charter");
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var height = charter.style.height | 100;
var mMargin = main.style.marginTop | 80;

charter.onmouseover = down;
charter.onmouseout = up;

function down() {
    if (height < 200) {
        height += 10;
        mMargin -= 10;
        charter.style.height = height + "px";
        margin.style.marginTop = mMargin + "px";
        setTimeout (down, 20);
    }
}

function up() {
    if (height > 100) {
        height -= 10;
        charter.style.height = height + "px";
        setTimeout (up, 20);
    }
}
</script>
```

The page loads, and nothing happens when I mouse over the div. I checked the error log, and the first error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. That's followed by a bunch of Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED, and then at the end there's a Widget configuration is not found. Perhaps it's in the way I'm defining mMargin? I might be supposed to use something different than marginTop, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Where in the page is the script tag? The `head`? Start or end of `body`? Somewhere in the middle (if so, before or after `charter` and `main`)?

Comment: It's directly after the charter div, so in the top-quarter of the <body> tag. I know it's not a problem with placement (kinda) because it was working fine before I tried to implement the margin change (when I was just changing the height of the div).